# New version of SQL Server Management Studio can't log into my web hosts database

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have recently started moving my development environment to a new computer; moving from Win 7 to Win 10. I set the new computer up and downloaded the current version of SQL Server Management Studio, V18.1. I can log into my web host's database using SSMS on my old computer but when I try from the new computer using same credentials I get the error message

> Login failed for user '****'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider).

Particulars are:
Server Name: Server IP address
Error Number: 18456
Severity: 14
State: 1
Line Number: 65536

The SQL server is version 2012. I have not had issues previously when connecting to an older version of SQL Server with a newer version of SSMS. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: did you tried to connect with osql on the new computer?  i bet the problem isn't SSMS.

Comment: Are you sure it's SSMS v18.1? From 2019? Current version is [SSMS v18.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms).

Comment: My error in version, it is 18.7.1. Have not tried osql. How would that help troubleshoot SSMS connection?

Comment: Verified that I can ping the server, and connect to it via Telnet using port 1433. I know the user name and password work on that server as I can connect via SSMS on another computer, using a previous version of SSMS.